# Django-Python-Use python modules that aren't installed on the host server

Tags: python, django

I want to use a python module on my django website (matplotlib) that isn't installed on the host server. Is this possible? I found some information about virtualenv, but I don't know if this does what I want. Can someone help me find information about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the host won't allow you to install the module, you can always just include it in your django project. Modules will work the same no matter where they get added to the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualenv may or may not be an option on your host, depending on how it invokes your application.  In either case, building matplotlib and placing the resulting package in the same place your application lives is probably adequate.  You can add that path to `sys.path` before importing it the first time if the pythonpath doesn't already contain that location.  Roughly

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append("/path/to/your/extra/packages")
 import matplotlib
```

The path should be the folder that *contains* the extra package, not the package directory itself

Comment: Thanks TokenMacGuy, that solved it...It looks so easy this way that the question becomes really silly...sorry, I'm beggining using python and django...